# Javascript says my function is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm debugging Ext JS and I came across this piece of code.  For some reason, javascript tells me one minute that field.setChecked is a function and the next minute it tells me otherwise.  What in javascript could cause an error like this???
[image]

Comment: Where is field.setChecked assigned?

Comment: Uhhh, the value of `field` has apparently changed and is no longer an object with that method.  Without seeing more of the actual code that is running, we can't really offer much more specific help.  It's rare for methods to just disappear from an object - it's more likely the value of `field` has changed somehow and it isn't what it's supposed to be.

Comment: jfriend00: I doubt that it's changed as I've "frozen" it in the debug console.

Comment: Gyro: good question. I should look into that.

Comment: You can freeze an object in Javacript so you've probably frozen the object that `field` points to.  You can't freeze a variable so `field` is not frozen - it can still be modified elsewhere.  Just do `console.log(field)` and `console.log(typeof field.setChecked)` in both cases to see what you actually have.  Also, freezing the object itself will probably make things like `setChecked()` stop working if they are attempting to modify instance data.

Comment: If you're doing this on successive calls to `setGroupValue()`, then perhaps the `this` point in `setGroupValue()` is different or wrong, so we'd benefit from seeing your `setGroupValue()` is being called too.

Comment: is there any way it could be anything besides 1. parallel events changing field, or 2. a scope issue?

Comment: Please insert `console.log(field)` into the loop in app.js code for testing.

Comment: The best way to provide a sourcecode. It is app.js - so self-written code and there could be a number of issues. Just assumption - in getSameGroupFields applies "for...in" construction to array, and as a result the last element is not a field. But without seeing sourcecode it will be difficult to get error

Comment: @yorlin That was your guesstimate, because the OP clearly does not provide all required info. I have found that extjs6-modern's `Ext.field.Radio`, line 133, contains exactly the source code shown in the browser's source code window. I have to assume OP used Sencha cmd to compile a "development" build.

Comment: @Alexander: yes, that's what I did.  the code shown above is from Ext JS itself, not from my custom-written app.js.

Comment: I ran all of those lines in the console log while the debugger was frozen on the step shown in the pic.  there was no time for anything to change.

Comment: As wrote Alexander put console.log(field) between 102169 and 102170 lines to get know what is field in time when it has no method. Regarding console - there could be some code in Source->Watch section, which modifies the value of the field, so you did nothing but console did. Anyway there is not enough info to investigate the problem. At least the value of the field should be known.

Answer (score 1):

As I get you have Ext.form.field.Checkbox. This component does not have `setChecked()` function. Replace it by `setValue(true)`.

`setChecked(true)` can be used for Ext.menu.CheckItem component

Comment: While this answer is not correct (compare ExtJS6-modern's `src\field\Radio.js`, line 133 ff., to find exactly the source code shown in the debug window), I fear that the problem here is that OP does not provide the required details.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can figure is that Google Chrome is having a rare debugger error and not displaying the output correctly.  the third value in the fields array doesn't have a setChecked function, and I think it's getting confused and showing me the value for the third one as opposed to the first one like it appears to be doing.  Somehow it's out of sync.